# How to disable deep import in Tslint ot tsconfig?

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to disable deep import in tsconfig?

I want to restrict import deeper that library path: `import { * } from '@geo/map-lib';`

I have tried this, but it is still allow use it like `@geo/map-lib/src/...`

```
{
    "extends": "../../tslint.json",
    "rules": {
        "import-blacklist": [true, "@geo/map-lib"],
        "directive-selector": [true, "attribute", "lib", "camelCase"],
        "component-selector": [true, "element", "lib", "kebab-case"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure we share the same goal, but this works for me:

```json
    "import-blacklist": [
      true,
      [
        "rxjs/Rx",
        ".*projects/.*",
        ".*observations-library/.*"
      ]
```

Result (in WebStorm):
[image]